# Seleccionar con Jquery sólo el hermano antecesor del ancestro directo de un resultado usando el buscador de Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

El caso es el siguiente, estoy usando este "snippet" de código `Jquery` que encontré que me facilita la búsqueda de elementos en el `html` sin recargar.

```
 var buscador = $(".buscador");

 //Activar el buscador
      buscador.keyup(function() {    
        _this = this;
 // grupo de cosas que se ocultaran
        $.each($("#grupo-busqueda ul li"), function() {
          if (
            $(this)
            .text()
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(
              $(_this)
              .val()
              .toLowerCase()
            ) === -1
          ){
            $(this).hide();
          }
          else {
            $(this).show();
          }
        });

      });

    });
```

Y tengo una estructura de `html` no puede cambiar:

```
<h3>título</h3>

<article class="subseccion">

  <h4>Lista 1</h4>
  <ul class="lista">
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Lista 2</h4>
  <ul class="lista">
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
  </ul>

</article>

<h3>título</h3>

<article class="subseccion">

  <h4>Lista 1</h4>
  <ul class="lista">
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Lista 2</h4>
  <ul class="lista">
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
  </ul>

</article>

<!--..etc se repite en bucle-->
```

Y me funciona, pero, la idea es que los títulos de cada resultado de búsqueda se mantengan (para que se sepa en qué categoría están los resultados) y el resto de títulos también desaparezcan.

Intente agregando esto:

```
$(this).parent().parent().prev().show();
```

Pero, no funciona en todas mis pruebas o esconde todos los `<h3>` o los muestra todos.

**¿Que estoy haciendo mal?**

A continuación esta es una demo simplificada de lo que he intentado de momento:

```js
// Write on keyup event of keyword input element
$(document).ready(function() {

  // VARIABLES GLOBALES
  var web = $(document); 
  var buscador = $(".buscador");
  
  //función para abrir los plegables
  buscador.focus(function(){
    $(".lista").toggleClass("open");
  });
  
  //Activar el buscador
  buscador.keyup(function() {    
    _this = this;
    // grupo de cosas que se ocultaran
    $.each($("#grupo-busqueda .subseccion li, #grupo-busqueda .subseccion"), function() {
      if (
        $(this)
        .text()
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(
          $(_this)
          .val()
          .toLowerCase()
        ) === -1
      ){
        $(this).hide();
      }
      else {
        $(this).show();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('h3').hide()
        //Actualizado segun respuesta dada y no funciona
        $(this).parent().parent().prevAll('h3:first').show();
      }
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h3 id="th">Talento Humano <b>TH</b></h3>

<div id="grupo-busqueda">
  <section class="configuracion">
    <h5 class="titulo">Configuración</h5>
    <input class="buscador" type="text">
  </section>

  <h3 id="th">Talento Humano <b>TH</b></h3>

  <article class="subseccion formatos">

    <h4 title="clic para ver el resto de archivos" tabindex="1">Formatos</h2>

    <ul class="lista">
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            ENTREGA DE CARNET
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            ENTREGA DE TARJETAS INGRESO EDIFICIO
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO ACTUALIZACION DE DATOS EMPLEADOS
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO INDUCCION DE PERSONAL
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO ENTREGA EQUIPOS DE TRABAJO
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO HOJA DE VIDA
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO LEGALIZACION GASTOS DE VIAJE
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO SOLICITUD CAPACITACION
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO SOLICITUD DE AUSENTISMO
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO SOLICITUD DE PRESTAMOS
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO SOLICITUD DE VACACIONES
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO SOLICITUD GASTOS DE VIAJE
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO INSCRIPCIÓN-ACTUALIZACIÓN DE DATOS DE PROVEEDORES
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO PAZ Y SALVO RETIRO DE PERSONAL
          </a> </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO REQUISICION DE PERSONAL
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO LISTA DE CHEQUEO DOCUMENTOS EN CARPETAS EMPLEADOS
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO VERIFICACION DE REFERENCIAS LABORALES
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO PERFIL DE CARGO
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO ENTREVISTA PERSONAL
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            SOLICITUD DE DOCUMENTOS
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO CITACION A DESCARGOS
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            ACTA DE DESCARGOS
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            LLAMADO DE ATENCION
          </a>        
      </li>
    </ul>

  </article>
  <article class="subseccion procedimientos">

    <h4 title="clic para ver el resto de archivos" tabindex="2">Procedimientos</h2>

    <ul class="lista procedimientos">
      <li>
        <b>TH-P-1</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            PROCEDIMIENTO DISCIPLINARIO
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li><b>TH-P-2</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            PROCEDIMIENTO DE SELECCIÓN Y RETIRO DE PERSONAL&nbsp
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li><b>TH-P-4</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            PROCEDIMIENTO SOLICITUD DE GASTOS DE VIAJE
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li><b>TH-P-3</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            PROCEDIMIENTO LEGALIZACION DE GASTOS DE VIAJE
          </a>        
      </li>
    </ul>

  </article>

  <h3 id="lc">Gestión en la liquidación y cierre de proyectos <b>LC</b></h1>

  <article class="subseccion formatos">

    <h4 title="clic para ver el resto de archivos" tabindex="3">Formatos</h2>

    <ul class="lista formatos">
      <li><b>LC-F-1</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
          MATRIZ CONTRACTUAL
        </a>        
      </li>
    </ul>

  </article>
  <article class="subseccion procedimientos">

    <h4 title="clic para ver el resto de archivos" tabindex="4">Procedimientos</h2>

    <ul class="lista procedimientos">
      <li><b>LC-P-1</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
          PROCEDIMIENTO DE IDENTIFICACIÓN DE REQUISITOS LEGALES Y OTROS
        </a>        
      </li>
    </ul>

  </article>

  <h3 id="de">Direccionamiento Estratégico <b>DE</b></h1>

  <article class="subseccion formatos">

    <h4 title="clic para ver el resto de archivos" tabindex="5">Formatos</h2>

    <ul class="lista formatos">
      <li><b>DE-F-1</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO ANALISIS DE IMPACTO AL NEGOCIO
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><b>DE-F-2</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
          ACTA DE REUNION
        </a>        
      </li>
    </ul>

  </article>

  <h3 id="gd">Gestión Documental <b>GD</b></h1>

  <article class="subseccion formatos">

    <h4 title="clic para ver el resto de archivos" tabindex="6">Formatos</h4>

    <ul class="lista formatos">
      <li><b>GD-F-1</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            CONTROL DE INGRESO A ÁREAS RESTRINGIDAS
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li><b>GD-F-2</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            FORMATO REPORTE Y GESTION DE INCIDENTES DE SEGURIDAD DE LA INFORMACIÒN
          </a>        
      </li>
    </ul>

  </article>
  <article class="subseccion procedimientos">

    <h4 title="clic para ver el resto de archivos" tabindex="7">Procedimientos</h2>

    <ul class="lista procedimientos">
      <li><b>GD-P-1</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            PROCEDIMIENTO DE CONTROL DE DOCUMENTOS
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li><b>GD-P-2</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            PROCEDIMIENTO DE CLASIFICACION Y ETIQUETADO DE LA INFORMACION
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li><b>GD-P-3</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            PROCEDIMIENTO DE AUDITORIA INTERNA
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li><b>GD-P-4</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
            PROCEDIMIENTO DE GESTION DE CAMBIOS
          </a>        
      </li>
      <li><b>GD-P-5</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
          PROCEDIMIENTO DE GESTION DE INCIDENTES DE SEGURIDAD DE LA INFORMACION
        </a>        
      </li>
      <li><b>GD-P-6</b>
        <a title="clic para abrir en otra ventana" target="_blank" href="#">
          PROCEDIMIENTO DE MONITOREO DE INFRAESTRUCTURA
        </a>        
      </li>
    </ul>

  </article>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Por si no ha quedado claro, en la demo anterior, en el resultado de la búsqueda, aún se ven todos los `<h3>` y la idea es que no se muestren, que solo se vean los `<h3>` que estén antes del `<article>` que si contiene el resultado de la búsqueda.

Agradecería cualquier pista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con esto coges el primer h3 de todos los previos al elemento.

```
$(this).parent().parent().prevAll('h3:first').show();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#click').parent().parent().prevAll('h3:first').css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>título1</h3>

<article class="subseccion">

  <h4>Lista 1</h4>
  <ul class="lista">
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Lista 2</h4>
  <ul class="lista">
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
  </ul>

</article>

<h3>título 2</h3>

<article class="subseccion">

  <h4>Lista 1</h4>
  <ul class="lista">
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Lista 2</h4>
  <ul class="lista">
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li id="click"><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
  </ul>

</article>
```

ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/gjt1osza/7/

Comment: Hola, he probado añadiendo selector modificado como me dices en el snippet del buscador, pero no me funciona. :C. Añadí lo que me dices a la demo de mi pregunta, para que cuando tengas tiempo lo revises gracias.

Comment: Claro, porque en ningún momento estás ocultando los demás h3.
Por ejemplo podrías poner:
   $(this).parent().parent().find('h3').hide();  antes de la linea nueva que has puesto